# Do not delete files that are younger than 1 hour

Tags: php

I want to check a folder on my server for files that are older than an hour old every 30 minutes, so I set up a cronjob to do that. As I am fairly new to php I had to browse a bit to find a solution that does not delete my parent/target directory and I found one!

```
<?php
deleteContent("/var/www/html/downloads/");
function deleteContent($path){
  try{
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ( $iterator as $fileinfo ) {
      if($fileinfo->isDot())continue;
      if($fileinfo->isDir()){
        if(deleteContent($fileinfo->getPathname())){
        if((time()-filectime($fileinfo->getPathname())) < 600 )
        {
          @rmdir($fileinfo->getPathname());
        }
      }
    }
      if($fileinfo->isFile()){
        if((time()-filectime($fileinfo->getPathname())) < 600 )
        {
        @unlink($fileinfo->getPathname());
      }
      }
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ){
     // write log
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
?>
```

Notice that the `if((time()-filectime($fileinfo->getPathname())) < 600 )` was my approach of finding a solution to my time problem.

The script should not delete folders or files that are younger than 1 Hour so I took the time we have now and subtracted it by the time, that the file/folder was changed the last time and compared it to 600 seconds (10 Minutes) just for testing purposes.

Sadly the script still deletes every file no matter when it was created.

Am I doing something wrong or does anybody has another approach?

Thanks

Comment: print the values of time() & filectime($fileinfo->getPathname() function and check out them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sometimes calling the underlying OS's functions is the better approach

```
exec('find /var/www/html/downloads/ -type f -mmin +60 -exec rm {} \;');
```

exec: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
php function to run the cli command
find, which finds the files in the path specified, of the type f(for file) with a file time greater than 60 minutes old, then exec(run) rm which is linux remove(delete)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not only new to php but also to ubuntu as this is my first project using a server! Could you please provide information about what everything is doing as I dont quite get the code? Thanks :)

Comment: And does it do so recursive? As my tree is like that: 

Target->FoldersXYZ->FilesXYZ 

Edit: and what about the folders?

Comment: to make it recursive add `-r`. `-type f` will only match files if you want folders deleted jsut remove it